# Can Drupal 8 Form #states API be used to expand/collapse <details>

Tags: 8, javascript, forms

Given a checkbox field with two options:

- "Closed" (selected by default)
- "Open"

I'd like to expand or collapse the `<details>` container of a different field (in our specific case an Address field). In HTML terms, this means adding the `open` HTML5 attribute to the `<details>` tag and adding `aria-expanded=true` to the `<summary>` tag when the "Open" radio button value is clicked, and ensure it is removed when that radio option is not selected (which means by default at page load time as well).

I've found a few [older](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236778) [semi-related](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/767212) issues and the [documentation page for Drupal 8's `drupal_process_states`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.6.x), but it's looking like this isn't possible with the Form `#states` API in Drupal 8. The docs do not include "open" in the list of valid states that may be applied to an element.

The valid states are:

- enabled
- disabled
- required
- optional
- visible
- invisible
- checked
- unchecked
- expanded
- collapsed

One would think that maybe the `expanded` and `collapsed` options could work, however this does not seem to be the case with my sample code below:

```
function mymodule_form_node_<type>_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_address']['#states'] = [
    // Expand address field container when the Trigger field is 'Open'.
    'expanded' => [
      ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => [
        'value' => 'open'
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Replacing 'expanded' state with 'open' in the above does not work, nor does the inverse logic using 'collapsed' state work:

```
function mymodule_form_node_<type>_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_address']['#states'] = [
    // Collapse address field container when the Trigger field is 'Closed'.
    'collapsed' => [
      ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => [
        'value' => 'closed'
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm going to answer my own question:  **`expanded` and `collapsed` states *do work* for the `<details>` type**.

My problem was operator error.  I was adding the `#states` array at the level of the `'#type' => 'container'` but the container has a widget inside of it that holds the `'#type' => 'details'`.   Fun times with Form API!

The working code is this:

```
<?php
// In mymodule.module
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymodule_form_node_<type>_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_address']['widget'][0]['#states'] = [
    // Expand location field when the Type is 'On-site'.
    'expanded' => [
      ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => [
        'value' => 'open'
      ],
    ],
    // Collapse location field when the Type is 'Online'.
    'collapsed' => [
      ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => [
        'value' => 'closed'
      ],
    ],
  ];

  // Load edit form with Location field either open or closed, based
  // on the value of the Trigger field.
  $form['field_address']['widget'][0]['#open'] = ($form['field_trigger']['widget']['#default_value'] == 'open') ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using **expanded/collapsed** use **open/close** like below:

```
function mymodule_form_node_<type>_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_address']['#states'] = [
    // Expand address field container when the Trigger field is 'Open'.
    'open' => [
      ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => [
        'value' => 'open'
      ],
    ],
    'close' => [
      ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => [
        'value' => 'closed'
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: I mentioned in passing on OP that I tried this and it didn't work.  I've tried again to be sure, and I can't make it work.  Are you sure there is code in Drupal 8 that works with open/close states?

Comment: Yes it's in Drupal8. See this link for demo https://files.fm/u/5fcyr5xd

Comment: Yes, open/close works in Drupal8.